# Rust compiler complains that a type parameter is never used

Tags: rust

I have been reading the book "the rust book" [chapters 17](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html) and think the last demo code in the chapter is excellent, and then I think maybe it could probably more concise like this :

```rust
struct Draft;
struct PendingReview;
struct Approved;

struct Post<State> {
    content: String,
}

impl Post<Draft> {
    fn new() -> Post<Draft> {
        Post {
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str) {
        self.content.push_str(text)
    }

    fn request_review(self) -> Post<PendingReview> {
        Post {
            content: self.content,
        }
    }
}

impl Post<PendingReview> {
    fn approve(self) -> Post<Approved> {
        Post {
            content: self.content,
        }
    }
}

impl Post<Approved> {
    fn content(&self) -> &str {
        &self.content
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut post = Post::new();

    post.add_text("I ate a salad for lunch today");

    let post = post.request_review();

    let post = post.approve();

    assert_eq!("I ate a salad for lunch today", post.content());
}
```

However, when I execute it, an error is reported:

```
hello:master* λ cargo run -q
error[E0392]: parameter `State` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 | struct Post<State> {
  |             ^^^^^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `State`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
  = help: if you intended `State` to be a const parameter, use `const State: usize` instead

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0392`.
error: could not compile `hello` due to previous error
```

does somebody know how to make rust compile happily?

---

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions the compiler made? Especially the one about `PhantomData`

Comment: Yes, I tried. Sorry, mine didn't quite understand how it worked very well at the time. I know it's meant to solve the problem, but it's a little hard to declare marker variables explicitly when constructing a Post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use every generic type in the struct definition. If you don't actually need to use it, you can use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) to tell the compiler about it:

```
struct Post<State> {
    content: String,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<State>,
}
```

And initialize it like this:

```
Post {
    content: String::new(),
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData,
}
```

This won't actually take up any space inside your struct.